# how to create multiplatform file browser in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, filepicker

I need help. I'm trying to create a multiplatform mobile application. One of the functionalities is a local file browser that will allow user to select a directory and create a list of file in this directory. I've already spent couple of hours on that issue and I can not find any solution for that.

I've checked http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

But if I understand it correctly it is used when I already have a file, it not allows user to pick the directory.
I don't need anything fancy, it should as simple as possible

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/krystiangw/filepicker-ionic-example Simple solution using filepicker.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cordova FileSystem plugin (and ngCordova's wrapper) provide the ability the read directories from the file system. They do not provide any UI, so you would use the plugin to ask for a list of directories and then render it as you see fit. (A UL, a table, whatever.) To "browse" you could use a click handler on the list of directories such that when clicked, you then get the files/subdirectories of *that* folder. Again, the FS plugin adds support for doing that.

Comment: I did it today in the morning. My main problem was that I've focused too much on the documentation of this plugin, my friend told be to look in the source and we've managed to create this kind of file browser. But your answer is the solution :)